# React Native - Loading local image in Image

Tags: ios, image, react-native

I use actual React Native and try to show Image with file that is loaded & saved by `react-native-fs` in app's Caches folder (on iOS Simulator)
In my component's `render` method I use this :

```
let logoPath = '/Users/emerkushev/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/33E9E1E9-70EF-4DCF-AAC7-AD194F567F14/data/Containers/Data/Application/AEA3B326-EF82-418F-915F-9657E0DEE3DE/Library/Caches/111709.102.logo.png'
...
<Image source={{uri: logoPath}} style={{width: 300, height: 300}} />
```

It generates an error message in debug console:

```
Image is not defined
    handleException @   ExceptionsManager.js:63
    handleError @   InitializeCore.js:114
    reportFatalError    @   error-guard.js:44
    guard   @   MessageQueue.js:48
    callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue  @   MessageQueue.js:107
    (anonymous) @   debuggerWorker.js:71

ExceptionsManager.js:71 Unhandled JS Exception: Image is not defined
    reactConsoleErrorHandler    @   ExceptionsManager.js:71
    console.error   @   YellowBox.js:61
    logIfNoNativeHook   @   RCTLog.js:38
    __callFunction  @   MessageQueue.js:236
    (anonymous) @   MessageQueue.js:108
    guard   @   MessageQueue.js:46
    callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue  @   MessageQueue.js:107
    (anonymous) @   debuggerWorker.js:71
```

How does need to show properly this type of image files?
Also I tried to add `file://` to the `logoPath`, but this had a same result.

Answer (score 2):

Shame on me: I just had forgotten to add `import {Image} from 'react-native'`.

Comment: :/ `Image is not defined`

Comment: Yep, I read and understood it as 'image _file_ is not defined'.

Comment: well, thanks buddy, was stuck with the same silly mistake. f me.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to `require` the images like so:

```
logoPath = require('/Users/emerkushev/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/33E9E1E9-70EF-4DCF-AAC7-AD194F567F14/data/Containers/Data/Application/AEA3B326-EF82-418F-915F-9657E0DEE3DE/Library/Caches/111709.102.logo.png');
<Image source={logoPath} />
```

Why? Because of [this](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.42/docs/images.html#why-not-automatically-size-everything)